# Regular Expression for Name in jQuery Validator

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

What will be the regular expression here for "Name" that contains a-z, 0-9, -, _ ?

```
$.validator.addMethod("validName", 
    function(value, element) {
        return /.....*/.test(value);
    }, 
    "Invalid name"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this :

```
    return /^[a-z0-9\-_]+$/.test(value);
```

It tests the string contains at least one of those chars and no other chars (the `^` and `$` are the start and end of string anchors).

If you want to allow the regular space () and the dot, use

```
    return /^[a-z0-9\-_\ \.]+$/.test(value);
```

Comment: how to include <space> and <dot> as well ?

Comment: See edit. And [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) might be useful too.